# Copying specific data from one sheet to another using value entered

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, lookup

Here is my scenario.
I have 2 sheets in a book. I enter info for 2 different businesses into the sheets and need to be able to verify the same info based on 2 criteria (hence the 2 sheets) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9aEC.jpg)

ATM I am entering the information into both sheets.  I'd like to enter the info into the Invoice # sheet and have C, D, and A auto populate into Job Tickets sheet once I enter the ticket# into F.
And vice versa, when I enter info under a particular job ticket #, it would be awesome if it would populate into the invoice # sheet once I enter the invoice #.
I'm sure it has something to do with a lookup function etc, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information, and it might help if you described your process in more detail.  It sounds like you want to be able to enter information into *either* sheet and have it populate into the other sheet.  That won't work. A cell in Excel can either hold data that is entered by the user **or** contain a formula that produces its data.

Comment: Okay,  that makes sense.  I'm okay with entering it only in 1 sheet... I just don't want to be spending extra time entering the same information in both.  As for more detail.  hmm...

Comment: Can you see the screenshot of the sheets in my original post?  Anyway, I receive job tickets from my field hands for pump jobs, from which I create an invoice.  I am entering the information from those tickets into "tickets" sheet, so I can keep track that I'm receiving all the tickets from all hands.  then internally I'm creating invoices to bill for those tickets, after which I am entering those into the "invoice" sheet.  Does that help?